# Can you force SQL Server to send the WHERE clause to Linked Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I'm trying to determine if a table in my SQL Server 2012 database has any records that don't exist in a table that's on a linked Oracle 11g database.

I tried to do this with the following:

```
select 1 
from my_order_table ord 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] 
                  where doc_id = ord.document_id)
  and document_id = 'N2324JKL3511'
```

The issue is that it never completes because the `ORDERS` table on the linked server has about 100 million rows and as per the explain plan on SQL Server, it is trying to pull back the entire ORDERS table from the linked server and then apply the `WHERE` clause.

As per the explain plan, it views the remote table as having an estimated 10000 rows - I assume that's some kind of default if it is unable to get statistics..?

Even running something as simple as this:

```
select 1 from LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] where doc_id = 'N2324JKL3511'
```

causes SQL Server to not send the WHERE clause and the query never completes.

I tried to use `OPENQUERY` however it won't let me add the `doc_id` to concatenate into the `WHERE` clause of the query string.

Then I tried to build a select `FROM OPENQUERY` string in a function but I can't use `sp_executesql` in a function to run it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a correlated subquery there. The only way you can compare the data between 2 servers would be one needs to transfer to **whole** dataset to the other.

Comment: Why is it that "it won't let me add the doc_id"? Are you having trouble with the single-quotes?

Comment: Does this OPENQUERY work for you?

`SELECT 1 FROM OPENQUERY (LINK_ORA, 'select 1 from [SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] where doc_id = ''N2324JKL3511''')`

Comment: How does something like `SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT document_id FROM my_order_table WHERE document_id='N2324JKL3511') ord LEFT REMOTE JOIN LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] ora ON ord.document_id = ora.document_id WHERE ora.document_id is null` perform? My thinking is to limit the size of the left table then use the "remote join" hint to push the join into the remote database.

Comment: Is your business requirement that your final query be callable as a function? Or can it be a stored procedure or ad-hoc query?

Comment: Also, is the document_id specific to an order, or are there many orders for any one document_id?

Comment: @Isaac, yes, that works fine.

Comment: @pwilcox the business requirement is that the final solution is a SELECT query that executes successfully from the SQL Server.  One record in my_order_table may have none, one, or multiple rows (less than 20) in the Oracle ORDERS table.

Comment: @Larnu.  I disagree that you need the full data set for what I'm doing.I have a limited set of data on the SQL server side and I want to validate whether any of those have NO records on the Oracle side.  What I would hope the compiler would do is run a Nested Loop through the SQL table and for each row it finds, query the Oracle table for that specific document.I think it's capable of this if both sides are SQL because it can get stats but since it's guessing the Oracle table stats it seems to be viewing it as more efficient to grab everything (as it guesses the Oracle table is 10k records)

Comment: @Isaac, for your first question, I can't run a query like this:  select 1 
from my_order_table ord 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from OPENQUERY(LINK_ORA, 'SELECT 1 FROM [SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] where doc_id = ''' + ord.document_id + '''')
  and document_id = 'N2324JKL3511'  because SQL server won't let you put dynamic SQL in the OPEN_QUERY call

Comment: @ThatGuyOverThere your SQL Server instance will have no knowledge of the statistics of the Oracle.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's precisely the issue.  I was hoping there was some way to tell it that the Oracle table was massive.  Seems there is not...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would logically work for you, but it may take too long as well.

```
SELECT    sql_ord.*
FROM      my_order_table               sql_ord
LEFT JOIN LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] ora_ord ON sql_ord.document_id = ora_ord.doc_id
WHERE     sql_ord.document_id = 'N2324JKL3511'
          AND ora_ord.doc_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server still tries to pull the full table back from Oracle as per the explain plan

Answer (score 0):

Since you have problem with something as simple as `select 1 from LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] where doc_id = 'N2324JKL3511'` have you try to create a table on the remote server that will hold the `doc_id` that you want to look at. So your `SELECT` will include a table that contain only 1 row. I'm just not sure about the `INSERT` since I can't test it for now. I'm assuming that everything will be done on the remote server.

So something like :

```
CREATE TABLE LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].linked_server_doc_id (
doc_id nvarchar(12));

INSERT INTO LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].linked_server_doc_id (doc_id)
SELECT doc_id 
FROM LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[ORDERS] WHERE doc_id = 'N2324JKL3511';

select 1 
from my_order_table ord 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].[linked_server_doc_id] 
                  where doc_id = ord.document_id)
  and document_id = 'N2324JKL3511';

DROP TABLE LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].linked_server_doc_id
```

Comment: unfortunately the linked Oracle server is read-only (vendor owned).  I tried to do a SELECT 1 FROM DUAL which works fine (returns immediately).

Comment: @ThatGuyOverThere Are you able to create a temporary table `CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE LINK_ORA..[SCHEMA1].ora$ptt_` ?